# How to remove brackets from a string?

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm, replace

I'm trying to solve a string replacement problem; A function that takes in a string and object of values.

It's a 2 part algorithm:

1. Replace values in the string that are inside of braces.
2. If it's in double braces, remove the outer braces; these are escaped sequence.

Example test case:

```
expect(replaceValue('The sky is [condition] and the color is [[blue]]', {'condition':'clear')).toBe('The sky is clear and the color is [blue]');
```

I solved the first part:

```
function replaceValue(input, replacementValue){
  let copied = input;

  Object.keys(replacementValue).forEach(ele => {
    copied = copied.replace(`[${ele}]`, replacementValue[ele]);
  })

  return copied;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to do the 2nd part; remove the outer braces.

Comment: you can replace the {{ }} with [[ ]] then do your replacements, then replace [[ with { and so on

Comment: Ahh sorry, it was supposed to be []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A negative lookbehind helps us to avoid replacing keywords enclosed in double brackets (`[[` and `]]`):

```js
function repl(str,obj) {
    return str.replace(/(?<!\[)\[([^\]]+)\]/g, (_, s) => obj[s] || s);
}

console.log(repl('The sky is [condition] and the color is [[blue]]', { condition: 'clear' , blue:'#0000ff'}));
```

Explanation:

The regular expression
`(?<!\[)\[([^\]]+)\]/g`
consists of

- `(?<!\[)`: a negative lookbehind, demanding the previous character is never a `[`
- `\[`: a single `[`
- `([^\]]+)`: a group consisting of at least one non-`[` character. This group will be used in a callback function of the `.replace()` method
- `\]/g`: a final `]` character and the end of the regular expression with the qualifier `g` for global, allowing this pattern to be matched multiple times.

Differently to Nina's solution mine will not replace the key `[[blue]]` in the string, although a replacement value would have been available.

Answer (score 3):

You could look for square brackets and replace only with knowing properties or take the returned value.

```text
/\[([^\[\]]+)\]/g  complete regular experession
 \[          \]    outer brackets
   (        )      group for content
    [^\[\]]+       inside all characters but not brackets
                g  search global
```

```js
function replaceValue(string, replacements) {
    return string.replace(/\[([^\[\]]+)\]/g, (_, s) => replacements[s] || s);
}

console.log(replaceValue('The sky is [condition] and the color is [[blue]]', { condition: 'clear' }));
```

Comment: That works :) but I'm not sure what the regex is doing

Answer (score 2):

Using a [negative lookahead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#other_assertions), you can ensure that one bracket is not followed by another.

```js
function replaceValue(input, replacementValue) {
  return input
  .replace(/\[(?!\[)([^\]]*?)\](?!\])/g, function(m, p) {
    return replacementValue[p];
  })
  .replaceAll("[[", "[")
  .replaceAll("]]", "]");
}
console.log(replaceValue('The sky is [condition] and the color is [[blue]]', {'condition':'clear'}));
```

Answer (score 1):

use a regular expression, match starts with two opening brackets [[ and ends with two closing brackets ]], replace it with the string inside the brackets with one pair of brackets

```
function replaceValue(input, replacementValue) {
  let copied = input;

  Object.keys(replacementValue).forEach(ele => {
    copied = copied.replace(`[${ele}]`, replacementValue[ele]);
  });

  copied = copied.replace(/\[\[(.*?)\]\]/g, '[$1]');

  return copied;
}
```